# Javafx binding data across fxml

Tags: javafx-2

I am using two FXML files (actually multiple). I want to bind the behavior of controls across multiple fxml using binding. Example: I have a table in one fxml. Another fxml have some buttons. If I select one raw in table, I want to enable one of the buttons from the others fxml. If I select multiple raw in table, I want another button say multiButton to be enabled.

Is this possible ?
Please suggest.

Also please suggest any good weblink to better understand JavaFX binding.
The link from oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm have very minimal information's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you bind against the same java object (with JavaFX properties). Check that your two FXML are binded to the same java property reference. To manage that, try using IOC with Spring integration for instance.

You declare in a Spring bean your property, you inject it in your 2 FXML controllers, then you bind against it with FXML components. As it is the same object, if a property changes it will notify the two components.

Comment: Code example would have been more help full.